# Error adding Dataset in Smartface App Studio and about local.notifications

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, smartface.io

I am first mobile application developing on Smartface App Studio. I have tho question.

1- I see this error: `Access violation at address 00000000. Read of address 00000000` when add second Dataset. And does not run application on emulator or usb real phone until delete Dataset.

2- I read Local.Notifications guide but could not run notifications on phone screen. I saved dates to table but can not make them as reminder. Which page should i add the function block and how should i do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a problem is occured when adding a Dataset. Did you try with a second project ? It seems working with the latest version of Smartface App Studio which downloadable via Account page.

Local Notifications are not added to the calendar/reminder. These are app specific notifications.

First off all, you should create a local notification.

For example;

```
var localNotification = new Notifications.LocalNotification({
        id : id,
        fireDate : new Date(),
        alertTitle : "AlertTitle",
        alertBody : "Alert Body",
        smallIcon : "icon_notification_small.png",
        launchImage : "icon_notification.png",
        sound : "notifsound.mp3",
        repeatInterval : Notifications.CalendarUnit.minute,
        onReceivedNotification : function (e) {
            alert("onReceived");
        }
    });
```

It creates a notification for you and it works at given date.

If you want to immaediately show the notification , you should run that code below;

```
Notifications.local.presentNotification(localNotification);
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. Yes, i tried to create a new project. May be reinstallition software or windows solve this problem.

Where should i add these example codes? When i try to add it from the script editor to the page and run it with the emulator, i receive this error : There has been an unhandled application error, please check your code again.